# Cisco business cbs110-8t-d lag spike

Tags: cisco, lag

I bought this switch to have peace, no luck. I have 1 gbps fiber going into my main router. then I have an rj45 cat 6 wire that goes to my cisco 8 port switch. Then each port is used by an rj45 wire that goes to all the rooms in my house, including my office. My pc is plugged into the office outlet. I have lag spikes when I go through the switch (games, work, zoom, etc.), however if I plug the office wire directly into the main router, I don't have any lag spikes. Any tool or idea why this happens? Have to return the switch?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Most likely, the cable is the problem, not the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide more specifics on what you mean by a 'lag spike'. Lag is generally accepted to mean an undesirable amount of round trip time delay for a given network path (source to destination and back again). Most often this is measured via ICMP Ping which sends a small packet of diagnostic data and waits for a reply and then measures the time that passes from send to reply being received.

What constitutes 'lag' varies from network to network and by the application in use. For example, when downloading text and image data from a website, a round trip time of 100 to 150 milliseconds or more is fine for most user experiences since you are simply clicking a link and waiting for a small amount of data to download and be displayed in your browser. However for an application like voice over IP phone service, once you exceed about 80 milliseconds round trip time, you can start to notice a subtle delay in the call and once you pass 120-150 ms (millisecond) of RTT (round trip time), you may experience issues that are very noticeable such as an echo or talking over the other person on the call, etc.

For a highly interactive video game such as a competitive shooter, RTT ping times under 50 ms are desirable or you can experience issues with aiming or other problems in the game, though many games implement 'netcode' software features to make games playable with much higher ping times.

A 'lag spike' would generally indicate that you have acceptable ping times from your computer to *something* and then while you are using that resource, the ping time suddenly increases for a period of time.

Lag on a local area network is generally very rare as long as the equipment is functioning correctly (no faulty cabling, etc.) and you are not exhausting the network's capacity. Your switch is capable of 1 Gigabit of throughput on each port and should be able to provide that level of performance without issue. It will likely provide the same performance as any 1 Gigabit capable small, unmanaged switch such as a TP-Link, Netgear or similar. It being aimed at 'business use' but still unmanaged means essentially it probably is physically more durable due to the metal case and may have a longer warranty vs. something sold for home use but performance will be identical.

You don't mention what you are doing when this lag spike happens or how you measure it so I'll assume you are doing something on the internet since that is the most common issue of this type that people experience. Usually gaming is the common problem. If so, your internet service and your gateway/router are much more likely to be the cause of the issue. Unfortunately that kind of consumer equipment and internet service is offtopic here. My recommendation would be to check your ISP account to see if they can provide you usage information and to also check if other devices on your network may be causing heavy use of the internet service.